# On page load for chrome, ie, ff triggers form validation error message in PHP

Tags: php

if($username=="") {
        $login_domain_error="Enter User Name";
    }

```
if(isset($_POST['passwd'])) {
    $login_p_error="Enter Password";
```

When I enter the above two validation, it triggers the validation errors, without form submission using PHP

What exactly is wrong

Thanks
Jean

Comment: You're just opening that page without making a form submission? Unless you have $username explicitly set to something already it's always going to be empty ( or equal to "") and trigger the first error.

Comment: I want to trigger it once the form is submitted

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're checking if `$_POST['passwd']` is set, and if that's the case, you define an error.

Comment: No I am checking if $_post['passwd'] is null, but then I used is_empty(_post['passwd']) too, with the same auto trigger for form error

Comment: isset() doesn't check for null values - it checks whether the variable exists but doesn't care whether it actually contains anything. Use print_r($_POST); to see what exactly is inside your array.

Comment: @hollsk: That's not entirely true. `isset()` returns true if the variable is set *and* it is *not* null. If you set it to `null`, it will still be "unset" as far as `isset()` is concerned.

Comment: Yes, you're quite correct, of course - the whole empty != null thing can be a slippery beast for an imperfect human mind sometimes :-)

Answer (score 0):

What's your error message?

Anyway, you should change `if(isset($_POST['passwd'])) {` to `if(empty($_POST['passwd'])) {` and add a `}` to that.

Comment: The error messages are $login_p_error and $login_domain_error

Does not work though....